# Saving HLS stream?

Tags: java, android, mp4, m3u8, mkv

I want to download an Video stream and want to save them to local storage with a single packeg as `MP4`.

All the info about the .ts files which are the chunks of the video stream are saved to a file which is named as info_media.m3u8 and this is how the `.m3u8` looks like :

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:4
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXTINF:4.000,
VideoChunk_00001.ts
#EXTINF:4.000,
VudeoChunk_00002.ts
#EXTINF:4.000,
VideoChunk_00003.ts
#EXTINF:4.000,
VideoChunk_00004.ts
#EXTINF:4.000,
VideoChunk_00005.ts
#EXTINF:4.000,
...
#EXTINF:0.600,
master_Layer1_02150.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Now my problem and the question is how to exactly download these chunks ?  The URL of the main .m3u8 is like `https://server.mine.it/video_id.m3u8` and the chunks URL
`https://server.mine.it/videoid_videochunk_*.ts`

Please help me to download these files. 
Answers with codes are really really welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

Using FFmpeg

```
String cmd = String.format("-i %s -acodec %s -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -vcodec %s %s", INPUT_FILE, "copy", "copy", dir.toString() + "/yourvideoname.mp4");
    String[] command = cmd.split(" ");
    execFFmpegBinary(command);
```

INPUT_FILE is your m3u8 url, and dir is file path to save.

```
   private void execFFmpegBinary(String[] command) {
    try {
        FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
        ffmpeg.execute(command, new FFmpegExecuteResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess: " + message);
                progressBar.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onProgress: " + message);
                progressBar.setMessage("Progressing: \n " + message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: " + message);
                progressBar.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                progressBar.show();
                Log.e("Time", System.currentTimeMillis()+"");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                progressBar.dismiss();
                Log.e("Time", System.currentTimeMillis()+"");
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/hadifar/Downloader-M3u8) is sample from github

Comment: Thank you very much @Tién for answering I really mean it. But I don't know how to add pause and resume for it ?, What if the network goes off and downloading is paused ? It will download the whole files again ? Really Waiting for your response...

Comment: Well I don't think there is a way to pause and resume download. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Of course there is a way, I've seen in apps, one is Videoder. But unfortunately I didn't found any way currently.

Comment: @Mark can you send me that app url on play store?

Answer (score 0):

As easy, as you can run this command, then just wait to finish the streams:

```
ffmpeg -i https://server.mine.it/video_id.m3u8 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

Thr FFMPEG do it for you!